# Qt C++ воспроизведение и остановка слайдера

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5

У меня есть две кнопки (Старт и стоп) и слайдер. Старт, соответственно, начинает воспроизведение, а стоп должна останавливать.

Написал код для кнопки старта:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
        slider->setValue(i);
        slider->repaint();
        usleep(1000000);
}
```

Но я не знаю, как его теперь всё то дело остановить :(
Подскажите, пожалуйста, буду крайне благодарен.

Comment: Идея в том что вместо sleep'а надо так или иначе вернуть управление QEventLoop'у. Обычных идеи тут две: вместо цикла создать таймер и двигать слайдер по сигналу от него; или в цикле создать таймер и свой QEventLoop, и подвесить QEventLoop::quit() на сигнал от таймера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как верно предложил @Fat-Zer, неплохим решением будет использовать `QTimer`.

```
start = new QPushButton("->");
connect(start, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(start_btn()));

stop = new QPushButton("||");
stop->hide();
connect(stop, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(stop_btn()));

timer = new QTimer();
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));

void start_btn() {
    start->hide();
    stop->show();

    timer->start();
}

void stop_btn() {
    stop->hide();
    start->show();

    timer->stop();
}

void update() {
    slider->setValue(slider->value() + 1);
    slider->repaint();
}
```

Comment: connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update_telemetry())); может так?

Comment: @Unick ну да, я просто название функции забыл изменить)

Comment: Если что, то именно это я и предлагал, как первый вариант `вместо цикла создать таймер и двигать слайдер по сигналу от него`

Comment: к стати, `repaint()` теперь избыточен.

Comment: @Fat-Zer ой, прошу прощения, не заметил в сообщений) Поправил в ответе.